# Capistrano deploy on windows fails with git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bash, capistrano

I am trying to deploy on windows machine with git bash.
Below is my staging.rb file.

```
set :stage, :staging
set :chruby_ruby, '2.2'
set :rails_env, :staging

#set :branch, '15_inaccurate-line-on-map'
set :branch, 'staging'

set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: true
}

set :rvm_roles, [:some]
set :rvm_map_bins, []

server 'XX.XX.XX.XX', user: 'deploy', roles: %w(web app db)
```

The repository is on bitbucket. I added my key on bitbucket and server.
So these commands are successful when I try on bash.

```
ssh deploy@XX.XX.XX.XX

ssh -A deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx 'git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git'

git pull origin staging
```

The problem is I see error on git:check when I am trying cap staging deploy

```
INFO [548342cf] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/butlermaps/ as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx
INFO [548342cf] Finished in 3.145 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading /tmp/butlermaps/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [2f19d649] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/butlermaps/git-ssh.sh as depl
oy@xx.xx.xx.xx
INFO [2f19d649] Finished in 0.487 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
INFO [61e3a414] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git
 as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx:
git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Error reading response length from authentication socket.
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.
rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.
rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Error reading response length from authentication socket.
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in
`exit_status='
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:179:in `block in _execute'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:133:in `tap'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:133:in `_execute'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:66:in `execute'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:11
:in `git'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:21
:in `check'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git
.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract
.rb:85:in `with'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git
.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:54:in `instance_exec'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.r
b:54:in `run'
c:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.
rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: 
git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Error reading response length from authentication socket.
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

Anybody has an idea why it fails on git:check?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem was actually deployment server git permissions. Deployment server wasn't able to get into repository because it's public key was added as a personal key to one of accounts which had access to repository before but which access was recently revoked, so deployment server access was revoked too.

It is a mistery though why `cap staging deploy` still worked for another dev (me). Maybe because I had oh-my-zsh and it was doing some magic proxying my ssh keys to staging server.

Actually, I found this question of you googling the error message I had trying to set up deploy for another developer, and that's quite funny.

So general solution would be: add your deployment server accounts to repository's 'deployment keys', people! Not to personal keys.